# Unmet dependencies error when installing postgresql 13 in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: lubuntu, postgresql

I am using this tutorial to install postgresql on my VM but when i am running
https://www.how2shout.com/linux/how-to-install-postgresql-13-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts-linux/

```
sudo apt install postgresql-13
```

I am getting the following error

```
~$ sudo apt install postgresql-13
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql-13 : Depends: postgresql-common (>= 182~) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libllvm14 but it is not installable
                 Recommends: sysstat but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have seen a lot of answers here but none of them answers this issue, hence posting it here.
Please help me in understanding why this issue is occuring, and please let me know the possible solution for it.

Comment: https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-postgresql-13-on-ubuntu/#:~:text=With%20the%20repository%20added%20we,available%20at%20the%20OS%20level.&text=The%20run%20the%20commands%20below,%7C20.04%7C18.04%20Linux%20system. Take a look at this link it appears to be quite clear and though.

Comment: It is clear but when i run "sudo apt install postgresql-13 postgresql-client-13" i run into error that is mentioned in my question.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1435214/edit) to show us the complete output of `sudo apt update` and the complete output of `apt-cache policy postgresql-13`

Comment: `libllvm14` is for 22.04, not 20.04. You may need to make some changes to your sources lists before you can install any further updates or software. You will want to check that `postgresql.list` file you created to see if it says `jammy`. If it does, that's your problem. You'll need to edit your `.list` files to be properly aligned with `focal` (20.04) 

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)